# Posting list of objects to web api method

Tags: jquery, post, asp.net-web-api

Hello I'm triying to post a list of objectos to a web api method this way:

```
var uri = "http://localhost:" + port + "/api/Account";
$.ajax({
    dateType: "json",       
    method: "POST",
    url: uri,
    data: JSON.stringify(schedule),
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("mal")
    }
})
```

My web api method is the following:

```
public IHttpActionResult createSchedule([FromBody]List<Schedule> schedule)
{
        return Ok(schedule.Capacity);
}
```

Well the problem is that is returning 0 instead of the number of the objects in the list. I assume that's because the list is arriving empty. What am I doing bad?. I read something about set data to `date: {"": schedule}` but it didn't work. It threw a null reference exception.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the data correctly, but you need to indicate that the content type of the request is JSON (the `dataType` option in the `$.ajax` tells jQuery what to expect on the *response*). Add the `contentType` parameter to the ajax call, and it should work:

```
var uri = "http://localhost:" + port + "/api/Account";
var schedule = [{}, {}, {}];
$.ajax({
    dateType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    method: "POST",
    url: uri,
    data: JSON.stringify(schedule),
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("mal")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

webapi method will look for `schedule` object

so change your `data: schedule,` to `data: { schedule: schedule },`

Comment: That is not the problem, since the method is working fine. Otherwise it wouldn't work fine. Anyway I've just tried it and it's still returning 0.

Comment: hmm.. is `schedule` look like `[{ },{ }..]`?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you say.

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake is en the web api method, because I'm testing with postman (chrome) and I'm getting null reference exception while I try to send this json:

```
var schedule = [{day: "Lunes", hour: "9-11", id_flat: 1},{day: "Martes", hour: "15-16", id_flat: 1}]
```